# Aligning some text and equations within the flalign environment

Tags: equations, align, flalign, aligned

I'm using the `flalign` environment because I need to have some text (Level1, Level2) to the left of some equations. Now, I'd like to add a third equation (β1j = γ10). However, this equation does not align with the first two equations.

```
\begin{flalign}
\begin{aligned}
    & \hspace{-3cm} \text{Level1:} & yij = \beta_{0j} + \beta_{1} x_{ij} + \epsilon_{ij}  & \label{eq:L1} &\\
    & \hspace{-3cm} \text{Level2:} & \beta_{0j} = \gamma_{00} + \gamma_{01 } z_{j}+ U_{0j} &\\ 
    & & \hspace{-3cm} \beta_{1j} = \gamma_{10} &\\
\end{aligned}
\end{flalign}
```

Right now it looks like this:
[image]

Any idea on how I can make the equations aligned at the equal signs, but still have the text to the left of the first two equations?

Thanks

Comment: Please allow a few hours to one or two days before accepting a solution in order to give the chance for other contributors to provide their solutions.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `&` character is used for alignment. I think you're looking to align on the `=` sign, so that's where you should be placing the ampersands:

```
\begin{flalign}
\begin{aligned}
    & \hspace{-3cm} \text{Level1:} & yij &= \beta_{0j} + \beta_{1} x_{ij} + \epsilon_{ij} \label{eq:L1} \\
    & \hspace{-3cm} \text{Level2:} & \beta_{0j} &= \gamma_{00} + \gamma_{01 } z_{j}+ U_{0j} \\ 
    &&  \hspace{-3cm} \beta_{1j} &= \gamma_{10} 
\end{aligned}
\end{flalign}
```

produces:

[image: output of above latex code]

Comment: Ah, I thought that the `&` were for separating... But that makes much more sense. Thanks!

Comment: The third `\hspace{-3cm}` doesn't do anything useful and should therefore be omitted. As there's a single numbered equation, there's no need for the outer `flalign` environment; I suggest you employ an `equation` number instead. Finally, it may be confusing that the `\label` instruction is stuck inside the `align` environment; I'd place it right after `\begin{equation}` and before `\begin{aligned}`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `flalign` does nothing really useful.

Here are two realizations:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

Really flush left, but requires an odd number of lines to get the equation number
centered
\begin{flalign}
&\text{Level 1:}
  & y_{ij} &= \beta_{0j} + \beta_{1} x_{ij} + \epsilon_{ij} & \notag\\
&\text{Level 2:}
  & \beta_{0j} &= \gamma_{00} + \gamma_{01 } z_{j}+ U_{0j} & \label{test} \\ 
&
  & \beta_{1j} &= \gamma_{10} & \notag
\end{flalign}

Not really flush left, adjust manually the dimension to suit your taste
(here it is three centimeters)
\begin{gather}\label{eq:L1}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
  &\makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[3cm][l]{Level 1:}}
  & y_{ij} &= \beta_{0j} + \beta_{1} x_{ij} + \epsilon_{ij} \\
  &\makebox[0pt][r]{\makebox[3cm][l]{Level 2:}}
  & \beta_{0j} &= \gamma_{00} + \gamma_{01 } z_{j}+ U_{0j} \\ 
  &
  & \beta_{1j} &= \gamma_{10}
\end{alignedat}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

Take your pick. Note: `showframe` is only used to display the margins of the text block.

[image]

The following is what I'd like to see:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

Not flush left, but probably clearer about your intentions
\begin{gather}\label{eq:L1}
\begin{alignedat}{2}
  \makebox[0pt][r]{Level 1:\quad}
  && y_{ij} &= \beta_{0j} + \beta_{1} x_{ij} + \epsilon_{ij} \\
  \makebox[0pt][r]{Level 2:\quad}
  && \beta_{0j} &= \gamma_{00} + \gamma_{01 } z_{j}+ U_{0j} \\
  && \beta_{1j} &= \gamma_{10}
\end{alignedat}
\end{gather}

\end{document}
```

[image]